# "Error: conflict: logging can't be satisfied" when running "meteor" command

Tags: ubuntu, meteor

When I try to run the command "meteor" in a project folder, all I get is the not-very-helpful message:

> Figuring out the best package versions to use. This may take a moment.
>   Refreshing package metadata. This may take a moment.
>   Could not resolve the specified constraints for this project:
>   Error: conflict: logging can't be satisfied

I've tried to disable all packages, one by one, but still the same error.

Comment: I had the same issue, reinstalling version 0.9.2 worked for me though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want to check the packages and see if this can be resolved at a packag eleve.

```
meteor list
```

If you receive the same error, then you will want to run meteor update again if you haven't already.

```
meteor update
```

This error seems to be mainly caused by the new meteor update `0.9.3.1`. I haven't seen reports of this happening in any previous versions.

Meteor did an update to the packages engine that allows *"More than one dash in package versions"*
http://screencast.com/t/Jz7AkyRlCyZ -- https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md

Which corrected issues from version `0.9.3` but caused issues in some other packages. I will monitor the change log closely to see if an update will be rolling out in version `0.9.4`.

I hope all is well,

Ryan